# C# class library reference

Tags: c#, class, reference

I have created a class library with target framework 4.0 and
some classes in it that deal with database connections for SQLite.

Now I want to use that class library in another project, to have
it connect to databases, query data, update rows and so on.

But when I "add reference" in the testproject, it seems "empty", 
i.e. in the object catalog, I cannot expand the referenced library.

And when typing the using statement, it says it is not known namespace.

What is wrong? Please help.

Comment: Aren't You referencing it in older .NET application? You can't reference .NET 4.0 from .NET 3.5 and older projects because 4.0 has new CLR.

Comment: can you add the screenshot or you can try check whether your current project is targeting same framework sometimes thats also a problem

Comment: Use the Browse tab, not the Project tab in that dialog.

Comment: Not sure why my comment went on as an answer! Damn mobile phones

Comment: Are you sure the classes in your external assembly are public?

Comment: Thank you so much! 

Happy about working everything that fine, i made a class library
from the classes in the testproject and forgot making classes public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid question really but are the classes definitely public in your external assembly?

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Solution Explorer' Right Click 'References' and then select 'Add Reference'.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your assembly may be using code that requires the full .net profile instead of the client .net profile.  Try changing the profile of the new project from Client to Full and see if that helps.

Comment: Nice thinking...! By default I do believe it selects the Client Profile!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was making the classes in den external assembly public.

Just forgot about that, after moving classes from testproject to classlibrary.
Thank you for helping!

Comment: Haha, should have put it on as answer :), I've done it before...scratched my head for 5 minutes trying to work out if the compiler wasn't doing its job, then realised they were marked private

Comment: Yes, in fact you did answer my question, and now i can mark your answer as solution! Thank you so much! Just didn't look there.